# What's wrong when not using singleton pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I'm reading about the singleton pattern from my ebook (Head First Design Patterns), and I know that using this pattern is suitable in case you need only one instance of some class.
But I have a little trouble with the problem introduction in this ebook. 
(Yeah, I think I can quote part of it here !?)

> **The Chocolate Factory** 
> Everyone knows that all modern chocolate factories have computer controlled chocolate boilers. The job of the
>   boiler is to take in chocolate and milk, bring them to a boil, and
>   then pass them on to the next phase of making chocolate bars.
>   
>  Here’s
>   the controller class for Choc-O-Holic, Inc.’s industrial strength
>   Chocolate Boiler. Check out the code; you’ll notice they’ve tried to
>   be very careful to ensure that bad things don’t happen, like draining
>   500 gallons of unboiled mixture, or filling the boiler when it’s
>   already full, or boiling an empty boiler!

```
public class ChocolateBoiler {
    private boolean empty;
    private boolean boiled;

    private ChocolateBoiler() {
        empty = true;
        boiled = false;
    }

    public void fill() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            empty = false;
            boiled = false;
            // fi ll the boiler with a milk/chocolate mixture
        }
    }

    public void drain() {
        if (!isEmpty() && isBoiled()) {
            // drain the boiled milk and chocolate
            empty = true;
        }
    }

    public void boil() {
        if (!isEmpty() && !isBoiled()) {
            // bring the contents to a boil
            boiled = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return empty;
    }

    public boolean isBoiled() {
        return boiled;
    }
}
```

Yeah, and this is their question:

> Choc-O-Holic has done a decent job of ensuring bad things don’t
>   happen, don’t ya think? Then again, you probably suspect that if two
>   ChocolateBoiler instances get loose, some very bad things can happen.
>   How might things go wrong if more than one instance of ChocolateBoiler
>   is created in an application?

So, the problem will "happen" when we do this:

```
ChocolateBoiler boiler1 = new ChocolateBoiler(),
 boiler2 = new ChocolateBoiler();
//...
```

But I see that these two instances control its own behavior, and they run independently (because no static field here).
 So they run separately without effect to the others.
 I wonder that this problem is about illegal state or something might happen when one instance run and effect to the others ("incorrect program behavior, overuse of resources, or
inconsistent results", from ebook), but it is not here

So, `How might things go wrong here?`, is it just about wasteful instance?

> if two ChocolateBoiler instances get loose, some very bad things can
>   happen.

I want to see how that `bad things` happen?

**#Edit 1:**
Thank everyone for helping me. I figured out what is my problem,

When I call `boiler2 = new ChocolateBoiler()`, the `boiler2` instance still refers to the same boilder as bolder1, is it?

The first time I think `new ChocolateBoiler()` is similar to buy a new boiler :)
This is about the conception, and I am a newbie here

Comment: There's only one boiler. What happens when two things try to control a single boiler?

Comment: Yeah,  two things try to control a single boiler can get illegal state, but their question is about problem when more than one instance of ChocolateBoiler is created?

Comment: There's a single boiler with two things trying to control it.

Comment: This is one of many reasons I don't like singletons.  The problem isn't that you need to ensure there is only one instance.  It's that you need one instance per boiler.  If you create one instance per boiler and bound them appropriately, it'd be fine.

Comment: Actually many researchers consider the *Singleton* pattern to be an *antipattern*. So one better doesn't use it.

Comment: How can this compile? Considering constructor is private: ChocolateBoiler boiler1 = new ChocolateBoiler() should not be possible

Comment: @John: It compiles just fine. It's just, that, as is, it cannot be instantiated. The code is just a temporary example in the mentioned book, and some code is added in order to instantiate a singleton.

Comment: Note that you can still run into problems, even with a synchronized singleton. For example, `ChocolateBoiler boiler = ChocolateBoiler.getInstance(); IntStream.range(1, 1000).parallel().forEach(i -> boiler.fill());` might fill multiple boilers at the same time, because of the time difference between `isEmpty()` and `empty=false`. See @John's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem not to understand the concept that this example is trying to explain. `ChocolateBoiler` is not a real boiler, it's a java class.

However, this class could be used to instruct a piece of hardware (a real boiler controller) to execute some actions. If you mistakenly had two instances of `ChocolateBoiler` and you mistakenly use both of them to instruct the same boiler controller, then obviously you're in trouble.

There are two 'mistakenly' in my previous paragraph, and you may argue that if you do things 'mistakenly' in general, then you're in trouble anyway. But in case of badly designed singletons, mistakes may not be so obvious. If you serialize and deserialize a singleton that does not handle serialization concerns to keep uniqueness, and then try to use that instance to heat the boiler, you could burn the boiler down.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of issues with Singleton pattern you should be aware of.
Let us consider two different singleton examples:

1) Stateless singleton

This singleton will have no field members and will only provide methods as services to outside world.

```
public class StatelessSingleton {

    private static final StatelessSingleton INSTANCE = new StatelessSingleton();

    private StatelessSingleton() {

        // exists to defeat instantiation
    }


    public void service() {
        //...
    }

    public void anotherService() {
        //..
    }

    public StatelessSingleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This type of singleton is usually better replaced with class that has only static methods, for performance reasons and readability. Exception might be when implementing pattern such as Strategy where you need to implement some interface as stateless algorithm, as it makes sense to cache this implementation. To implement interface, you obviously need an instance.

2) StatefullSingletion

```
public class StatefullSingleton {

    private int a = 3;

    private static final StatefullSingleton INSTANCE = new StatefullSingleton();

    private StatefullSingleton() {

        // exists to defeat instantiation
    }


    public void service() {
        // do some write operation on a
    }

    public void anotherService() {
        // do some read operation on a
    }

    public StatefullSingleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Now, on to problems with singletons:

Both of these singletons when poorly implemented can result with more then one instance. An example how this can happen would be if you use double-checked locking in java to ensure that only one Singleton instance exists:

```
class Foo {
    private Helper helper;
    public Helper getHelper() {
        if (helper == null) {
            helper = new Helper();
        }
        return helper;
    }

    // other functions and members...
}
```

There is plenty of resources available discussing why this does not work in java, so no need to reiterate this here.

One way to avoid issues with double checked locking is as shown above with private constructor and static reference to instance + getter.

Second problem, specific to StatefullSingelton is if your service methods are not synchronized, multiple threads can mess up state of such Singleton. In your example, if different workers are at the same time filling and draining boiler something might go wrong.

Third issue is Serialization. Given that Singleton implements java.io.Serializable interface, this can result with having more then one Singleton during deserialization. To avoid creating new object on deserialization, `readResolve` must be implemented.

Comment: nice analysis on java implementations of singleton patterns

Comment: Related to your second problem: I was surprised to see that, in the above example with ChocolateBoiler, even when Singleton is properly implemented, two workers (pointing to the same singleton ChocolateBoiler) could be filled at almost the time. With some bad luck, both `isEmpty()` can be called before `empty = false` is executed (twice), and both workers will happily try to fill the boiler.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of using **Singleton pattern**s is related to (or can be viewed as a variation of) [**Single Source of Truth** principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) and conflict management. **Single source of truth** is of course also a kind of conflict management.

Another aspect of singleton patterns is the need to minimise unnecessary duplication and/or (re-)initialisation for efficiency reasons.

For example two separate instances would conflict over the one and same resource, this depending on application and platform used (e.g multi-threading) can result in various problems like deadlocks, invalid states and so on.

The resource is one (singleton) so the manager or driver for this resource needs to take this into account to avoid potential conflicts over the same resource (see above).

Comment: Thank for the answer, but can you explain about the "problem" in my example ?

Comment: two separate instances of the Boiler would conflict over the one and same resource

Comment: this can result in various problems (depending on application and platform used), like deadlocks, invalid states and so on

Comment: there is no resource that these instance share with the other (in this version of example), @Nikos

Comment: no, they try to control ther same boiler, what would happen if one instance checks isEmpty() and then sleeps and the other instance then takes control boils and closes, then the fiurst instance will again take control and re-boil (invalid state)

Comment: and this exactly the problem, they dont share state, so their own states can result in conflict because the refer to the same resource at different times, so they can be out-of-sync, exactly because they dont share state